# enable disable image button

Tags: javascript

Here is what I'm trying to do and yes I have looked around this site for answers but I'm still lost. 
What I need help on is I'm making a game menu for and android and IOS (IPAD, IPHONE, ITOUCH) device.
The menu will have an image of text on it or just plain text.  The RED button is disable and the GREEN button is enable for example if the RED is showing you can hear the music play in the background and if you click it and shows GREEN the music will no longer play through the game. Same for the Skip Features too which will enable/disable the features.  Looking to do this in javascript.  Any advice will be helpful and thanks.

Since I can't post an image due to website rules.  I'll write it in as its on the menu.
Images = (RED) (GREEN)

---

Music (RED) (GREEN)

Skip (RED) (GREEN)

---

Comment: You should provide some code to show what you have so far. Don't expect the community to do all the work for you.

Comment: Sorry if I made it seem if I need someone to do it which all I need is help.

Answer (score 2):

See this DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/xQ3PT/

**Javascript Code**

```
function controls(id) {
    if (id == "play") {
        document.getElementById('play').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        document.getElementById('stop').removeAttribute('disabled','disabled');

        // You can define your play music statements here

    } else {
        document.getElementById('stop').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        document.getElementById('play').removeAttribute('disabled','disabled');

        // You can define your stop music statements here        
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
    Music&nbsp;<button id="stop" onclick="controls(this.id)" disabled="disabled">Stop</button>&nbsp;<button id="play" onclick="controls(this.id)">Play</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#stop{
    background-color: red;
    border: 0px;
}

#play{
    background-color: green;
    border: 0px;
}
```

**EDITED:**

Another Solution with a single Button:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/xQ3PT/2/

**Javascript Code**

```
function controls(className) {
    if (className == "red") {
        document.getElementById('PlayStop').setAttribute('class','green');
        document.getElementById('PlayStop').innerHTML = "Stop";
        // You can define your play music statements here
    } else {
        document.getElementById('PlayStop').setAttribute('class','red');
        document.getElementById('PlayStop').innerHTML = "Play";
        // You can define your stop music statements here        
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
    Music &nbsp; <button id="PlayStop" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'))">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ahsan Rathod.  That is what I'm looking for and as for the red and green button.  What if I made the two colors as one meaning one button.  when you click the red(disable) turns green(enable) does the same as two bottoms. How would I code it then. One button (2 images) instead or red(Stop) green(Play.)

Comment: Thanks – Ahsan Rathod your a life saver

Comment: @akamerc: if you fell the answer is fine and acceptable, then mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Demo http://jsfiddle.net/xQ3PT/46/
 I have two buttons that start off red and when you click them turns green. 
Each button is an enable/disable button red(Disable) Green(Enable). 
Been trying to get them to work right but when you click the first one the second one turns green, but the second one works fine. How can I get them to work right.

Comment: With one function and nested if else statements you can achieve this: see example: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ3PT/82/

Comment: How can I get the image button to function like the enable/disable button.  Mean when you click the image button it triggers the enable/disable button.  The way I'm trying to do it is both ways.

Comment: Here's my code `<td width="63%"><div align="center"><img src="images/menuIcons/skip.gif" width="58" height="30" vspace="5" /></div></td>
    <td width="37%"><div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
      <button id="Skip" class="red" onclick="controls(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)"></button>
`

Comment: Javascript `// enable / disable Buttons
function controls(className,elem) {
    if (className == "red") {
        document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('class','green');
        // You can define your enable statements here
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('class','red');
        // You can define your disables statements here        
    }
}`